# DB2 SQL update correlating with subquery

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update

Code block:

```
update yrb_purchase px 
  set px.club = (select club
                   from (select p.title, p.year, o.club, o.price, 
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.title, p.year 
                                                  ORDER BY o.price
                                                 ) rn 
                          from yrb_purchase 
                          inner join yrb_offer o    on p.title = o.title
                                                   and p.year = o.year
                          inner join yrb_member m   on m.club = o.club
                          inner join yrb_customer c on c.cid = p.cid
                                                   and c.cid = m.cid
                          where p.cid = px.cid 
                            and p.title = px.title
                            and p.year = px.year
                          order by title
                        ) 
                 where rn = 1
              ) 
 where ....
```

My issue is thus: upon execution of the above code, I get 'SQL0204N "PX.YEAR" is an undefined name. SQLSTATE=42704'. I was under the impression that in this case, the row being looked at by update would be passed into the inner query. What have I done wrong? The example I was given was:

```
update yrb_purchase P
set club = (
        select min(M.club)
            from yrb_member M, yrb_offer O
            where P.cid = M.cid
                and M.club = O.club
                and P.title = O.title
                and P.year = O.year
    )
where
    club <> (
        select min(M.club)
            from yrb_member M, yrb_offer O
            where P.cid = M.cid
                and M.club = O.club
                and P.title = O.title
                and P.year = O.year
    );
```

which was given as an example of bad code, but code that should work nonetheless.

Comment: ... why was this given as an example of bad code?  The iSeries version doesn't support joins in `UPDATE`s/`DELETE`s, so that's the only way to do that (barring something like temp tables.  Although you should avoid the implicit-join syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick test with DB2 (9.7 LUW) reveals that this works within one level of subquery, but not more than one.  This works:

```
update foo f
   set bar = ( 
       select count(*) from baz where f.bar = baz.bar
   )
```

This does not work:

```
update foo f
   set bar = ( 
       select count(*) from (
           select * from baz where f.bar = baz.bar
       )
   )
```

Why is this?  Who knows.  It is just one of many mysteries of DB2 syntax.

In any case, this is a bad style of coding (just like the person who gave you the example implied).  You should [use `MERGE`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0/2-10-6-154) when you want to do an update based on the contents of other tables:

```
merge into foo f
    using baz b 
    on foo.bar = baz.bar
    when matched then update set
        foo.bar = 123;
```

Answer (score 0):

To reference preceding tables, try including the `LATERAL` keyword in the nested table reference:

```
update yrb_purchase px
  set px.club = (select club from LATERAL (select p.title, p.year, o.club, ...
```

Don't have a DB2 9.7 instance to test it but I think it should work.